# Rpubs equivalence for Python

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter

[Rpubs](https://rpubs.com/) works great for sharing and posting r presentations. Is there an equivalent site for python, or more specifically Jupyter notebooks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can display your notebook from https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/ and host your notebook on https://gist.github.com/. In some cases I found that my notebook wouldn't quite render on gist but for the most part github should render your notebook for you. I use nbviewer as a backup for whenever github refuses to render the notebook; just copy the link of your gist into nbviewer and it should do the rest for you.

example: https://gist.github.com/pollend/7ab5bd156b15473be4421821e26cc469

Comment: Nice, I think I almost understand. Can you elaborate a bit more? You can upload to either nbviewer or gist.github. You use gist because github doesn't render .ipynb files? Also, why don't you simply use nbviewer, instead of git?

Comment: gist can render ipynb files but sometimes it doesn't work for some reason. you can work around this by pasting the gist link into nbviewer as a workaround.